# Font management and installation in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, fonts

Is there a way to detect if a font has fall back in the list of desired fonts, so that they can be dynamically downloaded and installed in the system?

Answer (score 3):

Silverlight does support font fallback in the FontFamily property -- just comma-seperate the list of fallback fonts.   You can also include fonts which you have embedded in your assembly (no need to install fonts).

Unfortunately, there is no way to download a font only if it is required using XAML alone, but the MSDN reference does suggest a code approach.

> FontSource
>
> Rather than specify a
>   FontFamily as a URI in XAML, you can
>   also specify a FontSource in code.
>   This gives you more options for
>   packaging or obtaining a font file.
>   Basically you obtain a stream of
>   either a font file or a zip of font
>   files, and set FontSource using that
>   stream. This is equivalent to
>   specifying a URI portion of a
>   FontFamily value, and makes that font
>   file available to the object. All you
>   need to do now is specify a
>   fontFamilyName to reference one of the
>   specific families in the current
>   FontSource value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Ok, what I mean is that there is no event raised at runtime that tells that a font doesn't exist in the fallback list.